# Implementing ZeroDivisionError exception in python

Tags: python, pycharm, divide-by-zero

SO, I'm a complete noob when it comes to programming, only just started learning python over the weekend gone. Anyway, as a challenge from one of the Youtube tutorials, I was suppose to write a program that can find all the numbers from defined range, that when divided by 4 will give me 0 reminder and then they will be listed. so i took it a bit further and below is what I've got so far.

```
# Program that let's you find all numbers in any range defined by user
# that can be divided without any reminder by the number also defined by user

print('Find all numbers in range...')

while True:
    try:
        x = int(input('From: ')) # begining of the range
        y = int(input('.. to: ')) # end of the range
        z = int(input('.. that can be divided by: ')) # value of the number to divide by
    except ValueError: # in case of a nonint input
        print('You should enter a valid number!')
        continue

    for a in range(x, y):
        try:
            if a % z == 0:
                print(a, [a / z], end = ' ') 
        except ZeroDivisionError: # issue with implementing this exception
            pass
```

To the point when instead of using pass statement, I try to do

```
print('You can\'t divide by 0!!') # or similar
```

it prints the string (x, y) times. Any suggestions? Many thanks in advance

Comment: I've tried your suggested scenario and it worked correctly, howether other way arround it seems to do... nothing, program terminates with code 0 with no values returned...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are try/except'ing inside the for loop.  If you don't want the program to terminate upon hitting the exception, just break the loop after printing your warning.

```
print('Find all numbers in range...')

while True:
    try:
        x = int(input('From: ')) # begining of the range
        y = int(input('.. to: ')) # end of the range
        z = int(input('.. that can be divided by: ')) # value of the number to divide by
    except ValueError: # in case of a nonint input
        print('You should enter a valid number!')
        continue

    for a in range(x, y):
        try:
            if a % z == 0:
                 print(a, [a / z], end = ' ') 
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            print ("Cannot divide by zero")
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to raise an exception Check the below sample

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

print('Find all numbers in range...')

while True:
    try:
        x = int(input('From: ')) # begining of the range
        y = int(input('.. to: ')) # end of the range
        z = int(input('.. that can be divided by: ')) # value of the number to divide by
    except ValueError: # in case of a nonint input
        print('You should enter a valid number!')
        continue

    for a in range(x, y):
        try:
            if a % z == 0:
                print(a, [a / z]) 
        except ZeroDivisionError as err: # issue with implementing this exception
            raise Exception("Cannot divide by zero", err)
```

Comment: If you want to solve it with an exception why not simply let the `ZeroDivisionError` propagate?

Comment: sorry I think I forgot to mention that my first language is not English. What propagate means?

Comment: @Varad thanks for suggestion, I run Your sample and it terminates the program, which is not my goal here.

Comment: @MichalFoc I think then you should not `raise Exception`. I am sorry I mistook your question. If that is the case, You can give a `print` statement and then use `break` to come out of the `for` loop to the `while`.

Answer (score 0):

how you call answering your own question? so I tried one thing that i haven't earlier instead of pass I used break statement and vuala. next I will try to make it write the results into a simple .txt file, here is the code so far for anybody interested

```
# Program that let's you find all numbers in any range defined by user
# that can be divided without any reminder by the number also defined by user

print('Find all numbers in range...')

while True:
    try:
        x = int(input('From: ')) # begining of the range
        y = int(input('.. to: ')) # end of the range
        z = int(input('.. that can be divided by: ')) # value of the number to divide by
    except ValueError: # in case of a nonint input
        print('You should enter a valid number!')
        continue

    for a in range(x, y):
        try:
            if a % z == 0:
                print(a, [a / z], end = ' ')
        except ZeroDivisionError: # in case of variable z = 0
            print('You shoudln\'t divide by 0!!')
            break
    break
```

Comment: If you want the program to terminate upon a divide-by-zero event, it's better to raise an exception as suggested by @Varad

Comment: that's not the case i would like to continue the loop until the user inputs correct values

Comment: Gotcha. My answer provides the functionality you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could validate the divisor entered by the user before entering the loop. Then you do not need to check for division by zero errors in the for loop:

```
while True:
    try:
        x = int(input('From: '))
        y = int(input('.. to: '))

        z = int(input('.. that can be divided by: '))
        if z == 0:
            print('You can\'t divide by 0!!')
            continue            

    except ValueError: # in case of a nonint input
        print('You should enter a valid number!')
        continue

    for a in range(x, y):
        if a % z == 0:
            print(a, [a / z], end = ' ')
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the only way that the `ZeroDivisionError` could be catched is if the content of the variable `z` is 0. At this point, I'm noticing some problems in your code :

1. Before passing x and y to `range()` function, you should ensure that `x < y`
2. You should always ensure that `z` is not null and then the script will just check wether it can divide in the way you want it or not.

Here is my proposition :

```
# Program that let's you find all numbers in any range defined by user
# that can be divided without any reminder by the number also defined by user

print('Find all numbers in range...')

while True:
    try:
        x = int(input('From: ')) # begining of the range
        y = int(input('.. to: ')) # end of the range
        z = int(input('.. that can be divided by: ')) # value of the number to divide by
    except ValueError: # in case of a nonint input
        print('You should enter a valid number!')
        continue
    numbers = range(x, y)
    if len(numbers) > 0 and z != 0:  #Check if the list is empty and if the divider is not null
        for number in numbers:
            if number % z == 0:
                print(number, [number / z])
    else:
        print("Invalid numbers passed")`
```

Comment: thanks Vinny, I like your whay of thinking and point 1 is definetly gonna be implemented as when I've tested it with x > y that gave me 0 results (altho program terminated with code 0...), howether I think that it's nice to have a educative bit, where You can inform/remind the user gently that You shouldn't be dividing by 0 :) as for checking the list wether it's empty or not, I thought it's handled with except ValueError. Thanks for your input